# How to create a database class object inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that needs to connect to the database to view its contents and in order to do that I need to get a cursor to my database. Now I have a database class as "DB" and a fragment class "FRAG" . To get a cursor I need to call certain methods of "DB" class inside my fragment. Now to call a method of "DB" class I need a object of "DB" class, the problem is that I am unable to initialize a constructor of "DB" class in fragment class. 
Syntax is as follows- 

 Original database constructor is

```
public DB(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
        super(context,"database", factory,1);
    }
```

I am initializing its object in fragment as follows-

```
DB ob=new DB(this,"database",null,1);
```

It gives me a syntax error as -

```
The constructor DB(Frag, String, null, int) is undefined
```

How do I initialize a object in this case. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is a descendant of the `Context` class, not the Fragment. 
You have to call the constructor with:

```
new DB(this.getActivity(),"database",null,1);
```

where `this` refers to your Fragment